# convert_tz is taking on GMT at the end of the date although I'm converting to East Coast Time

Tags: python, mariadb, convert-tz

So here the the time in the database...

```
2023-01-02 21:00:00
```

Here is the select that I use to get the information out of the database...

```
SELECT job_id,job_desc,
    CONVERT_TZ(job_date, 'GMT', 'US/Eastern') "job_date",
    cust_auto_id,
    cost,
    paid,
    mileage,
    (
    SELECT
    CONCAT(LastName, ',', FirstName) 
    from
    persons
    where
    jobs.person_id = persons.person_id) "Name"
    from jobs where job_id = %s'''
        cursorone.execute(sql,(1,))
```

Here is what is returned in the JSON block

```
{
  "Name": "Lterkdkflskd,Robert",
  "cost": "0.00",
  "cust_auto_id": 2,
  "job_date": "Mon, 02 Jan 2023 16:00:00 GMT",
  "job_desc": "Front Tires",
  "job_id": 1,
  "mileage": 123432,
  "paid": ""
}
```

Comment: is this a timestamp or datetime column?

Comment: the format you are seeing for job_date is something your database client is doing, not the mariadb server